# read a .sdf (SQL Server CE) in php

Tags: php, sql, sdf

I have a file called `PhotoGallery.sdf` and was wondering how to connect to this db with php, or if it is even possible?

Maybe point me to the right documentation. I found query strings for this, but not a db connect string...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to connect PHP to SQL Server Compact Edition?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/168240/is-it-possible-to-connect-php-to-sql-server-compact-edition)

Comment: For pointers: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Compact_Edition_Database_File - For duplicate reference: [Reading .sdf or .DB files in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5686922/reading-sdf-or-db-files-in-php)

Comment: read this https://www.rebasedata.com/php-read-sdf